# Securing device communication with API back-end with no user interaction

Tags: authentication, api

We have remote devices programmed in Python that talk to our back-end to update our database with information gathered from sensors connected to our remote devices. The remote devices are not interactive, so there is no user input. They simply talk to connected sensors and send the gathered data to our back-end.

We would like to secure access to those API endpoints so that not just anyone can just make calls and submit data if they know the payload format. We want to avoid storing API keys of any kind locally, but can't think of a way to get around that.

I've done quite a bit of googling, and searching on here, but can't seem to find the same kind of scenario.

Any help/insights would be wonderful.

Comment: Have you looked at mutual authentication models?

Comment: Just did per your suggestion. So as I understand it we would need to issue a certificate to the device on a per device level so that the cert can't be used on another device/system. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Another way to ensure the received data is valid is to use HMAC. An example for Python can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306550/calculating-a-sha-hash-with-a-string-secret-key-in-python

Comment: Fundamentally, you cannot control the client. A dedicated hacker with access to the device can always reverse-engineer it and do as they please.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan right on. Just seeing what our options are and what other people's suggestion are.